# Compose middlewares in next.js 14

Tags: next.js

I'm working on an app that requires both authentication and internationalization.

For authentication, I used `next-auth`. This gave me the following middleware:

```
import { auth } from "utils/auth";

/**
 * Use NextAuth for Middleware redirections
 */
export default auth; // auth is the auth() object returned by next-auth

/**
 * Match all request paths except:
 * - API
 * - NextJS chunks
 * - favicon.ico
 *
 * @see https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware#matcher
 */
export const config = {
  matcher: ["/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico).*)"],
};
```

Now, I was checking the `next-i18n-router` library to handle i18n. It requires updates to my middleware, which would then look like this (according to their doc):

```
import { i18nRouter } from 'next-i18n-router';
import i18nConfig from './i18nConfig';

export function middleware(request) {
  return i18nRouter(request, i18nConfig);
}

// applies this middleware only to files in the app directory
export const config = {
  matcher: '/((?!api|static|.*\\..*|_next).*)'
};
```

Now, how can I get the best of both worlds? I tried combining them as follow, but it doesn't work

```
const middleware = auth((req) => i18nRouter(req, i18nConfig));

export default middleware
```